# Get the value from created JTextfield at runtime

Tags: java, swing, runtime, jlabel, jtextfield

I've made an application that will get the column name of the database and create a jlabel and jtextfield at runtime based on the column names of the db.

Here's the code snippet: Im using Netbeans here...

```
 public void getColumn(){
        String sql = "SELECT * from user";
        jPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));

        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

            ArrayList<String> columns= new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i = 1; i<= columnCount; i++){
                columns.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(columns));
            }
            ArrayList<JTextField> fields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
        for(int i = 0; i <columns.size();i++){
                JLabel jl = new JLabel(String.valueOf(columns.get(i)));
            jPanel.add(jl);
            JTextField f = new JTextField(50);
            fields.add(f);
            jPanel.add(f);
                        this.revalidate();
                        this.repaint();
               }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This will be the sample output.

```
id | ______________
fName | _____________
mName | _______________
lName | ________________
```

lines referring to JTextFields..

However, I can't get the values entered in the jtextfields. I've tried using the code below. But no luck. Any help appreciated.

```
for(JTextField field : fields){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, field.getText());
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're shadowing your variables, but without further code it's impossible to know

Comment: I'm using netbeans here.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - this seems very familiar.  Did you ask this question in the last day or so?

Comment: Yes. I've asked a similar question regarding this one. But I've solved my problem to display the jtexfield and jlabel. i just don't know how to get the values from those jtextfields. Another member told me to post another question not to add another question in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this:

```
Component children[] = jp.getComponents();
for(Component child : children) {
  if(child instanceof JTextField) [
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ((JTextField)child).getText());
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't help without getting the detail code, especially where and how `jp` is initialized

Comment: *"I'll post my complete code"*  Please don't.  Prepare an SSCCE.

Comment: I've retested this code suggestion and it works. I've tested it in my pc at work and it didn't work. But when I've tested this one in my pc at home, it worked. Weird.
Thanks for all the help guys. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to use a JTable. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

You can also check out [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for some simple code to get you started. See the 'TableFromDatabaseExample' code for the easiest solution.

Comment: I don't need to output my query in a JTable. I just needed the column names of my database and then create a jlabel and jtextfield at runtime according to the column names of my db. I've already done displaying the jtextfields and jlabel at runtime according to my query. But I cant get the values from those JTextfields craeated at runtime.

Comment: I understand, that is why I suggested a JTable. It is a better display since it is more compact and you can easily scroll the table and you have access to the data via the TableModel.